# Proactive message using botkit on teams

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, botkit, proactive

I am trying to add new feature to the bot which is sending the message to some users proactively from the bot.  am working on botkit ("botkit": "^0.7.4") and language nodeJS(node v10.24.1 (npm v6.14.12)).

Below is the code sample:

```
let bot =  controller.spawn({"serviceUrl":"https://*****"});
params = { conversationType: 'personal', 
          tenantId: '66********',
          id: 'a:1*********',
          members: [
           {
            id: '29:1*********'
             }
          ],
          channelData: { tenant: { id: '6********' } },
          is_group: false
       }
bot.startConversationWithUser(params);
bot.say("hello");
```

Although it is not giving any error, but it is not sending the message. I checked all the documentation but fail to get any solution.

Can anyone suggest a way out where I am going wrong? Which is the right way to send proactive messages to the users on the teams?

Comment: Could you please refer to this link: https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I follow the link (Post a proactive personal message to a user) but I am not able to get the below parameters:
1. teamInternalId
2. mentionUserPrincipalName

Comment: I checked the message payload but I did not get any of the above-mentioned details. It will be great if anyone can help.

Comment: @lucifer - Could you please share the doc and sample code reference, so that we can try it our from our end?